# Disconnect/reconnect mobile data automatically/renew IP every N minutes?

Tags: automation, android-10

When I disconnect/connect mobile data, I get a new IP. I would like to automate that process, i.e., set up some kind of schedule that disconnects, wait 5 minutes, connects, wait 8 minutes, disconnects, wait 5 minutes etc. Can this be done?

Comment: Yes, with automation. See the questions Under that tag